# How do I change the color of an SF Symbols based UIButton embedded in a UIAction?

Tags: uibutton, uikit, uiimage, sf-symbols, uiaction

I'm generating a button with the following code but am unable to successfully change the button's foreground color.

```
let button = UIButton(
    type: .close,
    primaryAction: UIAction(
        image: UIImage(systemName: "x.circle"),
        handler: { _ in }
    )
)
```

I've tried

- `UIImage(systemName: "x.circle")?.withTintColor(.red)`
- `UIImage(systemName: "x.circle")?.withTintColor(.systemRed, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)`
- `button.setTitleColor(.systemRed, for: .normal)`
- Adding a configuration:

  ```
  var config = UIButton.Configuration.borderless()
  config.baseForegroundColor = .systemRed
  button.configuration = config
  ```
- Using a different symbol variant like: `UIImage(systemName: "x.circle.fill")`

In this specific scenario I want to change the color of the circular background area of the image only and not the X (crosses) or the button's background. Essentially I want a red filled circle with a gray X (crosses).

So I can get this:
[image]

But I want something more like this (with the red limited to inside the circle):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change type from `.close` to `.custom`
2. Change `UIImage(systemName: "x.circle")` to

   `UIImage(systemName: "x.circle")?.withTintColor(.systemRed, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)`

Answer (score 0):

Both of these work:

or

```
yourButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
var elements: [UIMenuElement] = yourData.map({ item in
    
    let conf = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(
                  paletteColors: [item.color]
               ).applying(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(
                  pointSize: 40,
                  weight: .heavy)
               )
    
    let acn = UIAction(
        title: item.name,
        image: UIImage(
               systemName: "map",
               withConfiguration: conf)
    ) { [weak self] _ in
        guard let self else { return }
        yourButtonProcess(item.code)
    }
    return acn
})
yourButton.menu = UIMenu(children: elements)
```

In the "palette", for some symbols use more than one color. You'll soon get the idea.

or

```
yourButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
var elements: [UIMenuElement] = yourData.map({ item in
    
    let acn = UIAction(
        title: item.name,
        image: UIImage(
            systemName: "map")?
            .withTintColor(
               item.color,
               renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) // don't forget
    ) { [weak self] _ in
        guard let self else { return }
        yourButtonProcess(item.code)
    }
    return acn
})
yourButton.menu = UIMenu(children: elements)
```

There you go.